# Guardar un ciclo for en un data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-dplyr

```
for (i in unique(hola$Partida)){

    hola%>%
    filter(Partida==i) %>%
    summarize(median(Valor.importado.en.2018)) %>%
    print()
   print(i)

}
```

Tengo una duda con este ciclo, lo que estoy tratando es de sacar la mediana de un grupo de partidas, el problema es que quiero guardar los datos  que me da el summarize en un data frame, alguien sabe como???

Answer (score 1):

¿Para que un ciclo si puedes usar `group_by()`?

```
hola %>%
  group_by(Partida) %>%
  summarize(median(Valor.importado.en.2018)) -> new_df
```

Con este código terminarás con un nuevo `data.frame` con cada una de las posibles `Partida` y la mediana de `Valor.importado.en.2018`